# ListJS Input a value and elements are deleted

Tags: javascript, list, listjs

I have a setup that I have replicated here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjrPbV

```
<div id="fac_content">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search">
  <ul class = "list" id="fac_list" style="display: block;">
    <li>
      <p class="fac_name">CheckOneTwo</p>
    </li>
    <p></p>
    <li>
      <p class="fac_name">FiveThreeOne</p>
    </li>
    <p></p>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
      valueNames: [ 'fac_name']
    };

    var userList = new List('fac_content', options);
</script>
```

The problem is that when I am implementing it in my website, when I enter in the search field, everything inside of `<ul></ul>` gets deleted, no matter the character I input. I realize that there must be something else that is causing this in my code, the question is, what could cause code to be deleted? Note that the list elements are being generated on startup in my website using AJAX and the innerHTML property.

Note, for me, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as found here: [Why are some rows disappearing when I sort or filter listjs table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953246/why-are-some-rows-disappearing-when-i-sort-or-filter-listjs-table/27085607#27085607)

(Referencing answer by brymcbride)

Issue was that I was making the list in listjs before the AJAX call. When I put the code right after the call was being made, everything worked out perfectly!